# How and when does onHandleIntent function get Called

Tags: android, intentservice

I am writing an app in Android where I need to run service in background every 5 minutes.

Now 1st question is:

1. Where do I put my code which is currently in "onCreate" function.
2. If I have to put it in onHandleIntent function,when does it get called?
3. Is there any way I can set my Intent to run once in every 5 minutes?

Comment: You can use `AlarmManager` for it which is best approach. Also you can call `Timer` in `Service` in `onStartCommand()` method

Comment: and when will onStartCommand() be called?

Comment: When your service will be started

Comment: So can I write my business logic in "onStartCommand()"?

Comment: Yes you can and there you can get intent data too

Comment: okay, and what if I want to keep my business logic in MainActivity and call my mainactivity from Intentservice?

Comment: Then you should use `BroadCastReceiver` with `IntentService` through which you can send result back to your activity.